# Haskell: Dealing With Types And Exceptions

Tags: exception, haskell, types

I'd like to know the "Haskell way" to catch and handle exceptions. As shown below, I understand the basic syntax, but I'm not sure how to deal with the type system in this situation.

The below code attempts to return the value of the requested environment variable. Obviously if that variable isn't there I want to catch the exception and return Nothing.

```
getEnvVar x = do {
    var <- getEnv x;
    Just var;
} `catch` \ex -> do {
    Nothing
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO a'
       against inferred type `Maybe String'
In the expression: Just var
In the first argument of `catch', namely
    `do { var <- getEnv x;
          Just var }'
In the expression:
      do { var <- getEnv x;
           Just var }
    `catch`
      \ ex -> do { Nothing }
```

I could return string values:

```
getEnvVar x = do {
    var <- getEnv x;
    return var;
} `catch` \ex -> do {
    ""
}
```

however, this doesn't feel like the Haskell way. What is the Haskell way?

Edit: Updated code to properly reflect description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot strip away the `IO` and return `Maybe String` within a do-block. You need to return an `IO (Maybe String)`.

```
getEnvVar x = do {
    var <- getEnv x;
    return (Just var);
} `catch` \ex -> do {
    return Nothing
}
```

---

Why not use

```
import qualified System.IO.Error as E
getEnvVar :: String -> IO (Either IOError String)
getEnvVar = E.try . getEnv
```

Instead of `Nothing` and `Just var`, you get `Left error` and `Right var`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get that anything involving `getEnv` is going to involve returning a result in the `IO` monad, then there is nothing wrong with your basic approach. And while you could use `System.IO.Error` (and I would), it is just as valid, and instructive, to write it the way you did. However, you did use a bit more punctuation than idomatic Haskell would use:

```
getEnvVar x = (Just `fmap` getEnv x) `catch` const (return Nothing)
```

or

```
getEnvVar x = getEnv x `catch` const (return "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
import System.Environment
getEnvVar :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
getEnvVar x = getEnvironment >>= return . lookup x
```

or a bit longer, but maybe easier to follow:

```
getEnvVar x = do
    fullEnvironment <- getEnvironment
    return (lookup x fullEnvironment)
```

if you don't mind going through the whole environment the whole time.

Comment: There's no need to use the power of monads here; `getEnvVar x = fmap (lookup x) getEnvironment` works just as well, and does require using `return`